# Adding a percentage to time range

Tags: sequences-and-series

I trying to add a percentage of time to time

Example 
Im not a math expert not even a savvy so bear with me please.
I have these times range

60mins
120mins
180mins
......
.......
........
1640mins

What is the formula that can use so i will be able to add 10% to any given time but still time stays in hours or hours and half.

Example

If i have 
120mins + 10% = 142mins then it will round to 150 mins 
If i have 
600mins + 10% = 660mins

Time must always be in hours or hours and half

Please ask me and i would love to clearify further.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If we have a time of $x$ minutes, adding 10% means multiplying by $11/10$ (so it's $\frac{11x}{10}$). If we want this to be a multiple of $30$ minutes, we have to divide by $30$ (making it $\frac{11x}{300}$), round to the nearest integer, and multiply by $30$, again. Rounding is done with the round (in computers) or floor (computers and mathematics) functions, so in mathematical notation, we'd arrive at
$$30\left\lfloor\frac{11x}{300}+\frac1{2}\right\rfloor.$$ In your first example, $x=120,$ so $\frac{11x}{300}+\frac1{2}=4.9,$ the integer part is $4$, and the result is $120$, and that's correct, because 120 + 10% is 132, not 142.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just one small thing i need it to be clarified is. What this kind of formula called?